# Is there any way to see which extras I can send with an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using a lot of different intents with adb and sometimes I want to send in extras, for example:

```
am start -n com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.EditEvent -e title 'my title'
```

This one will open up google calendar to edit event and have already written my title in the textbox. So that is great! But I can't figure out if there is some other way to see all the other extras (if any)? Except of going to the source code of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to find out all possible extras application can handle, but to look at source code or to find any documentation of intent handling of this app